# Create Jenkins Multi-Branch Pipeline Job from a Job DSL Factory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to create **Multi-Branch Pipeline Job** by a Job DSL which defines the Job **by "Pipeline Script"** **instead of Jenkinsfile** contained by each Git Repository?

We wanna avoid to generate and maintain the same Jenkinsfile (except some parameters) in each of our 100 Git Repositories.

At the moment we are using Pipeline Jobs with Job DSL seeded by a Factory Job, but we are limited at them moment with Multi-Branch Builds (Feature Branches). So we wanna switch to Multi-Branch Pipeline Jobs, but there we are limited in seeding them.

I know we could use a Jenkinsfile (Git Repo of Project) which includes other common Jenkinsfiles from the Jenkins, but that is just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Only pipeline jobs can have the pipeline defined inline. Multi-branch jobs can't and JobDSL can't change anything about that.

The probably better alternative is using a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). You can configure Jenkins to automatically load this library so that the particular `Jenkinsfile`s in all the repos only have to call a function out of that.

You can e.g. have a look at a `Jenkinsfile` of [a Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/analysis-core-plugin/blob/master/Jenkinsfile) - it only calls a function from the shared library:

```
buildPlugin()
```

In your case (as you wrote about "except some parameters"), this function could have some parameters that could differ by the different jobs. The `buildPlugin` function is implemented here in https://github.com/jenkins-infra/pipeline-library/blob/master/vars/buildPlugin.groovy.

While this would still require you to update all your repos, it is probably the better starting point to introduce pipelines in your organisation.